# Регулярное выражение (url без нижнего подчеркивания)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть такое регулярное выражение, которое распознаёт url:

```
preg_match('#^(https?|ftp)://[a-zA-z0-9]+([\-.][a-zA-z0-9]+)*/?$#', $link);
```

Всё вроде-бы работает корректно, но почему-то url нижним подчёркиванием, например: http://test_ing.com он распознаёт как верное. В чём может быть проблема? В выражение же нигде не фигурирует `"_"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Присмотритесь вот сюда

```
[a-zA-z0-9]
```

В промежуток от `A-z`, попадают все спец. символы. Правильное выражение:

```
preg_match('#^(https?|ftp)://[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\-.][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*/?$#', $link);
```

Comment: Да, действительно. Проглядел. Спасибо!
Если в промежуток A-z попадают все спецсимволы, то к примеру такой адрес: http://test#ing.com должен отработать верно, но он же отрабатывает false.

Comment: @PiterPan, Внимательно изучите символы юникода, в промежутке от A до a, находятся только [, ], \, ^, _, `.